# Alternative ways to fix timing issues

Tags: recording, mixing, logic-pro

I'd usually use Flex Time Polyphonic for such purposes but in this case it'll remove all tightness from the audio. But when I use Flex Time Monophonic, it creates a pop at the start of the transient (makes sense because notes are sustained and overlap each other) which is not a deal. I also tried to cut the tracks at the place where there's no signal.

[image: no signal]

Then I try to move it forward, stretch the regions to fill the void and apply a crossfade. Give the same effect: pop at the start.

So the small piece of part looks like this:

[image: part]

What can I do to keep the tightness of recorded audio, but still fix the timing issues. Re-recording will breed the same results (I mean, spending the whole day for recording 5 seconds perfectly, doing hundreds of takes is just not worth it, right). So, are there any alternate ways to perform this (maybe use an external software, not logic himself)?

Comment: idk Logic well, but are you certain you're cutting at zero crossings? DAWs usually have a pref for that. Pops [even after crossfade] would suggest otherwise & your "like this' is definitely not at zero. Some DAWs will cut at zero with a cut tool, but not using the position markers. Either that or you have a DC offset, which may be actually visible on that waveform. Another trick is to always cut slightly early, which naturally lands you in a low level area.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, that zero crossing for me (I recorded in take folders starting from such places and after crossfade was applied it sounded natural). The problem is that most zero crossing areas are too short to split and stretch from (cut, align to bar/beat/semiquaver, etc and fill the void), while Flex Time monophonic gives the same effect.

Comment: Your 'like this' point is not zero. That will cause clicks. Crossfades should eliminate those, but not always. A zero crossing can be found just about anywhere at all, it's just that the ones in quiet areas are the better place to cut anyway, not because they're the only places to find zero crossings. idk Logic, haven't used it since the 90s so idk how flex time behaves. Presumably it's a stretch not a cut, so would always be click-free. Cubase has an Iterative Q feature, which moves things **towards** quantise but doesn't just slap everything right on the tick. Maybe see if Logic has similar

Comment: I'd definitely run it through a DC-offset removal process before you play with it any further. It might be the sole cause of your issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin There was a 0.001% DC offset, however it didn't help. I still used Flex Mode Polyphonic, but in a slightly different way. I snap some notes to grid and let others flow normally but get pushed forward (or backward depending on what I choose), so I don't get extra artifact sounds. I still used it, but slightly gently.

Answer (score 1):

Don't record it hundreds of times in the vain hope you'll get it right by mistake!   Turn the computer off and practice playing it.  Half speed.  If you can't cut it at half speed go even slower.  Or (probably) sort out where you're fumbling it.   You've tried the computer quick fix.  Now fix it properly.